# Spring and Hibernate Upgrade from 4.x to 5.2.24(Spring) and 5.3.20(Hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have upgraded Spring and Hibernate from 4 to 5

Could someone please help on the mentioned issue as I have been stuck on this for a week

**RefundProcessingModel** class

```
public class RefundProcessingModel extends XModel{

private String VRR_REC_ID;

private String VRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM;

private String VRR_TRANSACTION_ID;

private String VRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER;

private String VRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER;

private String VRR_CUSTOMER_ID;

private String VRR_ACCOUNT_ID;

private String VRR_GL_ACCOUNT;

private String VRR_FROM_DATE;

private String VRR_TO_DATE;

private String VRR_CREATED_DATE;

private String VRR_STATUS;

List<RefundProcessingDataModel> details=new ArrayList<RefundProcessingDataModel>();


public RefundProcessingModel(){

    super.setTransferObjectName("com.tec.t.to.transaction.RefundProcessingTO");
    super.setControllerClassName("com.group.x.web.controller.transaction.RefundProcessingController");

}

public void reset(HttpServletRequest   request){
    this.VRR_REC_ID="";
    this.VRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM="";
    this.VRR_TRANSACTION_ID="";
    this.VRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER="";
    this.VRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER="";
    this.VRR_CUSTOMER_ID="";
    this.VRR_ACCOUNT_ID="";
    this.VRR_GL_ACCOUNT="";
    this.VRR_FROM_DATE="";
    this.VRR_TO_DATE="";
    this.VRR_CREATED_DATE="";
    this.VRR_STATUS="";
    details=new ArrayList<RefundProcessingDataModel>();
    getLovValues().clear();

}


public void convertToModelObject(RefundProcessingTO refundProcessingTO) {

    this.setOperationMode(refundProcessingTO.getOperationMode());
    this.setRowId(refundProcessingTO.getRowId()); 

    this.setVRR_REC_ID(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_REC_ID());
    this.setVRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM());
    this.setVRR_TRANSACTION_ID(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_TRANSACTION_ID());
    this.setVRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER());
    this.setVRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER());
    this.setVRR_CUSTOMER_ID(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_CUSTOMER_ID());
    this.setVRR_ACCOUNT_ID(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_ACCOUNT_ID());
    this.setVRR_GL_ACCOUNT(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_GL_ACCOUNT());
    this.setVRR_FROM_DATE(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_FROM_DATE());
    this.setVRR_TO_DATE(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_TO_DATE());
    this.setVRR_CREATED_DATE(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_CREATED_DATE());
    this.setVRR_STATUS(refundProcessingTO.getVRR_STATUS());

    if(null != refundProcessingTO.getDetails() && refundProcessingTO.getDetails().size()>0){
        List<RefundProcessingDataModel> detailsModeList=new ArrayList<RefundProcessingDataModel>();
        for(RefundProcessingDataTO detTo:refundProcessingTO.getDetails()){
            RefundProcessingDataModel detModel=new RefundProcessingDataModel();
            detModel.convertToModelObject(detTo);

            detailsModeList.add(detModel);
        }

        this.setDetails(detailsModeList);

    }

    super.copyToModelProperties(refundProcessingTO);
}

public void convertToTransferObject(RefundProcessingTO refundProcessingTO) {

    super.copyToTransferObjectProperties(refundProcessingTO);

    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_REC_ID(this.getVRR_REC_ID());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM(this.getVRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_TRANSACTION_ID(this.getVRR_TRANSACTION_ID());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER(this.getVRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER(this.getVRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_CUSTOMER_ID(this.getVRR_CUSTOMER_ID());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_ACCOUNT_ID(this.getVRR_ACCOUNT_ID());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_GL_ACCOUNT(this.getVRR_GL_ACCOUNT());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_FROM_DATE(this.getVRR_FROM_DATE());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_TO_DATE(this.getVRR_TO_DATE());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_CREATED_DATE(this.getVRR_CREATED_DATE());
    refundProcessingTO.setVRR_STATUS(this.getVRR_STATUS());
    refundProcessingTO.setRowId(this.getRowId());

    if(null != this.getDetails() && this.getDetails().size()>0){
        List<RefundProcessingDataTO> detailsToList=new ArrayList<RefundProcessingDataTO>();
        for(RefundProcessingDataModel detModel:this.getDetails()){
            RefundProcessingDataTO detTo=new RefundProcessingDataTO();
            detModel.convertToTransferObject(detTo);;

            detailsToList.add(detTo);
        }

        refundProcessingTO.setDetails(detailsToList);

    }

}

public String getVRR_REC_ID() {
    return VRR_REC_ID;
}

public void setVRR_REC_ID(String vRR_REC_ID) {
    VRR_REC_ID = vRR_REC_ID;
}

public String getVRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM() {
    return VRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM;
}

public void setVRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM(String vRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM) {
    VRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM = vRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM;
}

public String getVRR_TRANSACTION_ID() {
    return VRR_TRANSACTION_ID;
}

public void setVRR_TRANSACTION_ID(String vRR_TRANSACTION_ID) {
    VRR_TRANSACTION_ID = vRR_TRANSACTION_ID;
}

public String getVRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER() {
    return VRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER;
}

public void setVRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER(String vRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER) {
    VRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER = vRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER;
}

public String getVRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER() {
    return VRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER;
}

public void setVRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER(String vRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER) {
    VRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER = vRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER;
}

public String getVRR_CUSTOMER_ID() {
    return VRR_CUSTOMER_ID;
}

public void setVRR_CUSTOMER_ID(String vRR_CUSTOMER_ID) {
    VRR_CUSTOMER_ID = vRR_CUSTOMER_ID;
}

public String getVRR_ACCOUNT_ID() {
    return VRR_ACCOUNT_ID;
}

public void setVRR_ACCOUNT_ID(String vRR_ACCOUNT_ID) {
    VRR_ACCOUNT_ID = vRR_ACCOUNT_ID;
}

public String getVRR_GL_ACCOUNT() {
    return VRR_GL_ACCOUNT;
}

public void setVRR_GL_ACCOUNT(String vRR_GL_ACCOUNT) {
    VRR_GL_ACCOUNT = vRR_GL_ACCOUNT;
}

public String getVRR_FROM_DATE() {
    return VRR_FROM_DATE;
}

public void setVRR_FROM_DATE(String vRR_FROM_DATE) {
    VRR_FROM_DATE = vRR_FROM_DATE;
}

public String getVRR_TO_DATE() {
    return VRR_TO_DATE;
}

public void setVRR_TO_DATE(String vRR_TO_DATE) {
    VRR_TO_DATE = vRR_TO_DATE;
}

public String getVRR_CREATED_DATE() {
    return VRR_CREATED_DATE;
}

public void setVRR_CREATED_DATE(String vRR_CREATED_DATE) {
    VRR_CREATED_DATE = vRR_CREATED_DATE;
}

public String getVRR_STATUS() {
    return VRR_STATUS;
}

public void setVRR_STATUS(String vRR_STATUS) {
    VRR_STATUS = vRR_STATUS;
}

public List<RefundProcessingDataModel> getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(List<RefundProcessingDataModel> details) {
    this.details = details;
}}
```

The **ERROR** am facing is

```
Invalid property 'SOURCE_SYSTEM' of bean class 
[com.group.x.web.model.transaction.RefundProcessingModel]: 
Bean property 'SOURCE_SYSTEM' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: 
Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: 
Invalid property 'SOURCE_SYSTEM' of bean class [com.group.x.web.model.transaction.RefundProcessingModel]: 
Bean property 'SOURCE_SYSTEM' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'SOURCE_SYSTEM' of bean class 
[com.group.x.web.model.transaction.RefundProcessingModel]: 
Bean property 'SOURCE_SYSTEM' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

My **hbm.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.group.x.commons.entity.persistable.gst.VatRefundReq" table="VAT_REFUND_REQ">
    <id name="vrrRecId" type="big_integer" column="VRR_REC_ID" />
    <property name="vrrSourceSystem" column="VRR_SOURCE_SYSTEM" type="string" />
    <property name="vrrTransactionId" column="VRR_TRANSACTION_ID" type="string" />
    <property name="vrrGstInvoiceNumber" column="VRR_GST_INVOICE_NUMBER" type="string" />
    <property name="vrrConsInvoiceNumber" column="VRR_CONS_INVOICE_NUMBER" type="string" />
    <property name="vrrCustomerId" column="VRR_CUSTOMER_ID" type="string" />
    <property name="vrrAccountId" column="VRR_ACCOUNT_ID" type="string" />
    <property name="vrrGlAccount" column="VRR_GL_ACCOUNT" type="string" />
    <property name="vrrFromDate" column="VRR_FROM_DATE" type="timestamp" />
    <property name="vrrToDate" column="VRR_TO_DATE" type="timestamp" />
    <property name="vrrCreatedDate" column="VRR_CREATED_DATE" type="timestamp" />
    <property name="vrrStatus" column="VRR_STATUS" type="string" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Do note that everything was working before Spring and Hibernate upgrade.
Please find the attached screenshots of the issues faced and resolution done
[codechange1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz5zg.jpg)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIrT3.jpg)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ThLI.jpg)[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI1lQ.jpg)

Comment: Don't jump so many versions. Try first going to the latest 4.x, then fix all deprecations, then update to 5.0.x and fix all deprecations and so on. Also take a look at these [migration hints](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc#changedmoved-contracts)

Comment: The version you are trying updating to is already 3 years old, chances are that not many people did such a big jump in versions (or even the same jump) or that they did it long ago.

Comment: I have already done the upgradation of both Spring and Hibernate to 4.x latest version and it worked fine with some minor code level changes....most of the screens are working fine now except the screen related to this Java file where the screen is blank

Comment: Do you experience these problems also when you upgrade spring and hibernate to 5.0.x?

Comment: After upgrading to 4, I have tried with 5.2.24(spring)-and-5.3.20(hibernate) and I can't downgrade this to any other version due to them being vulnerable

Comment: I have added 4 screenshots of the changes I have done till now so please look into that as well

Comment: You have to increase the major version to the lowest available. You don't want to stop there but fix the deprecations accordingly and then progress to the next minor version and so on until you arrive at the latest desired.

Comment: I have downgraded spring jar versions to 5.0.0.RELEASE now but still facing the same error that I had mentioned before

Comment: Hi, I have resolved this issue and it was due to incorrect base profile in the DB that I had used. After using the correct updated DB it worked...Thanks for reaching out to help